# Adding an array to a dimension of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

I have 2 numpy arrays `img` and `mask` that I want to combine into a single array. The shapes of the arrays are as follows:
`image.shape = (512, 366, 3)` and `mask.shape = (512, 366)`. I want the final array to have a shape of `(512, 366, 4)`, such that the `mask` array occupies the 4th dimension.

What's the best way to achieve this, please?

Comment: use `np.dstack`

Comment: @Julien Thanks, that worked.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion from Julien works:

```
from numpy import stack
new_image = dstack(img, mask)
```